# Erro no Resultado do Execute SQLTask

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto onde em um de meus execute sql task possui uma query,

```
select stuff((select ',' + campo from tabela FOR XML PATH(''))1,1,'') as resultado
```

esta query retorna assim

```
|   resultado   |
|1,5,3,6,7,9,6,4|
```

e estou colocando esse valor dentro de uma variavel X que e do tipo String dento do meu package do SSIS.

ao fazer isso ele me retorna o erro:

```
[Execute SQL Task] Error: An error occurred while assigning a value to variable "X": "The type of the value (DBNull) being assigned to variable "User::X" differs from the current variable type (String). Variables may not change type during execution. Variable types are strict, except for variables of type Object.
```

".

```
[Execute SQL Task] Error: The value type (__ComObject) can only be converted to variables of type Object.
```

Comment: Sua consulta retornou vazio por algum motivo. Já na sua pergunta anterior sugeri que repense o que você quer fazer nesse package utilizando outros componentes, como Lookup ou Derived column. Talvez se você explicar o que exatamente você quer fazer fique mais claro.

Comment: Nao ha como usar o lookup pois estou dentro do Control Flow, e consegui resolver ja. o erro era que a query nao retornava String, entao tive que usar um cast ou convert pra resolver.